# URL rewrite to remove tildes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

During my company's annual security/penetration test, the following problem came up regarding tildes and shortname files for aspx pages:

[Here](http://soroush.secproject.com/downloadable/microsoft_iis_tilde_character_vulnerability_feature.pdf) is the white paper on the subject. It looks like a relatively newly discovered vulnerability (the paper is from June 2012) where inserting tildes in the right place in the url allows you to find the shortnames of your aspx files. I'm looking for a way to remove all tildes from a web request made to our website to prevent this.

The white paper suggests upgrading to IIS 7, but that's a major project that can't be completed very quickly. We're using C# .NET 4.0/IIS 6. Anyone with experience here that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the following code to global.asax :

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("~") Then
        'do whatever - eg: stip the ~ or redirect to error page
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't help with my particular problem. It looks like the way IIS processes the URL makes it so that when the methods in the whitepaper are used it never actually gets to any of your application code. I have always wondered what exactly the Global.asax file was for (Our website didn't have one, but I've seen them around), so I read up on it and played around a bit. What you suggested above does work to remove the ~s from a url if it gets to my application (which doesn't help me since my app is never getting called). I appreciate the chance to learn something new though.

Comment: You could use urlrewrite for II6 instead, this would process the request before getting to your application.